# Remove an application in recommended apps

Tags: wine, uninstall, playonlinux, software-uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, [image: OS here], and I have this small bug but it is stressing me out how to fix it.

I installed ms office on my system using PlayOnLinux, but then I decided to uninstall it. When I uninstalled it, together with PlayOnLinux,and now trying to open the file using "OnlyOffice", when I clicked on the "Open with other application" the application "word" is still being shown.[image: Here is the Screenshot]

How can I fix this? I tried autoremove & autoclean, but still nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. @guiverc